# Android RecyclerView Error

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, android-recyclerview

today I was trying to use the new android RecyclerView.
I have created a new Project with a blank activity and added the following to its layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In gradle build dependencies I have added:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
```

But the activity_main.xml rendering still shows me the following error:

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Open Class, Show Exception)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: accessibility   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService(BridgeContext.java:465
```

I don't seem to find a solution myself in the web since everyone says "implement the following dependencies in your gradle build: ..." which i have already added.

Can anyone provide a solution?

Regards 
Tak3r07

Edit:
onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: add also your code from onCreate(). You might missing something there.

Comment: @mt0s added - but i didnt change anything yet, since its a complete new project.

Answer (score 7):

I think that with RecyclerView you have at least to set the layout manager.

If you read the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager)) :

> In contrast to other adapter-backed views such as ListView or GridView, RecyclerView allows client code to provide custom layout
>   arrangements for child views. These arrangements are controlled by the
>   RecyclerView.LayoutManager. **A LayoutManager must be provided for
>   RecyclerView to function.**

You can try after instantiating the **RecyclerView** to set the LayoutManager like that :

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

( later change it to a `LayoutManager` that fits better your needs )

Comment: Sorry to answer that late, i did not get the time to get on with that project.
I have now created a LinearLayoutManager and an adapter and added both to the recyclerview but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Tak3r07 LayoutManager cannot be set in xml, that's why preview doesn't work for RecyclerView.

Comment: @MyDogTom It can be set in xml: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#attr_android.support.v7.recyclerview:layoutManager

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in Android SDK 21. If you upgrade to SDK 22 the problem should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is a bit old, but the problem still persists and it's a known bug.

Anyhow the bug seems to be close to get a patch:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72117

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade to SDK 22 and the problem is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Just change Api level on the top of the screen in your xml viewer and make it 21 api level it will be work . hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your build.gradle file under dependencies block

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good, Try to make a Invalidate chache/restart. I that will work for you. There may be a chache problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Hi hope this will help you
You have to remove scrollbars attribute from your view